# Make wysiwyg editor automatically go to the next line when it reaches the edge

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a problem with he wysiwyg editor.  When I enter a text and it reaches the end of the form, it doesn't automatically add a line break like what StactExchange does, but it goes on and on.

How can make this:

[image]

To appear this way?
[image]

Comment: I don't think TinyMCE supports that. You probably just need to apply `word-wrap: break-word` to the appropriate element, though

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where/how do I apply it?